# regularly refresh Chrome tab

Tags: automation, chrome-for-android, scripts

I have a Transformer Prime TF201 which I sit next to my main pc to display a webpage that shows stats about the systems I work on.

However this page is a bit rubbish for updating and will time out and log off and generally just not work all that well (its a home made iframe that just shows data from other sites).

On a windows system elsewhere I used a line of VBS to, effectively, hit F5 every 30 seconds and this basically resolved all the issues.

Can anyone think of a way to do this on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding extensions will solve this type of requirements.
But Chrome for android does not support any extensions yet.
Look at the [Chrome for Android FAQ](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/faq)

Or else you can use [Dolphin Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser&feature=related_apps) to achieve this.   It supports extensions.
If you are willing to use Dolphin Browser instead of Chrome, use this [Auto Reload Extension](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.tabreload&hl=en).
You can set time intervals in it.

Comment: No problem at all using Dolphin, just never had a reason until now. Thanks